# How to transfer a BQ table into Postgres table using Airflow

Tags: postgresql, google-bigquery, airflow

I have a BigQuery table in my GCP project space as well as a common Postgres database. My goal is to transfer the table from BigQuery to a new Postgres table using Airflow.

I found out there's an "PostgresToGCSOperator" but not a "GCSToPostgresOperator", or else I would have transferred my BigQuery table into gcs in some avro/csv/parquet format and then uses the GCSToPostgresOperator to transfer the data into a Postgres table.

Please let me know if there are any other alternatives like using dataflow etc. My current GCP project permissions are only for GCS, BQ, DataProc and CloudBuild, and I have provisioner role for the above.

I have simply researched until now as I am new to Airflow and don't know how to configure it with my GCP project and Postgres database simultaneously.

Comment: Which version of `Airflow` are you using ? Are you using Airflow in Cloud Composer ?

Comment: Hello @MazlumTosun, I am using Airflow 2.4.2 with Astronomer version 6.0.3. Using Cloud Build pipeline to run the ci cd and use astronomer to orchestrate my airflow pipeline

Answer (score 0):

Recently, [BigQueryToPostgresOperator](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/30658) got added in `apache-airflow-providers-google` and will be released in a couple of days.

But we have RC available and you can install that with

`pip install apache-airflow-providers-google==10.1.0rc2`

otherwise, wait for `apache-airflow-providers-google==10.1.0` to get released

Comment: Thank you @Pankaj for the quick response. Do you know any other way to do it...like maybe send data from bq to gcs first and then from gcs to postgres? I was not able to find the GCSToPostgres operator too. I am scared my versions and dependencies might be old and don't want to distrub the repo as my team members are also using it. Thank you

Comment: not sure, but you can always write your own operator or even a Python function to perform this and use PythonOperator. Or, you can explore https://github.com/astronomer/astro-sdk particular load_file operator to write GCS data in Postgres